# generate Xml file in particular format

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this code to generate Xml from an `IQueryable` variable query:

```
XDocument data = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server
                                           .MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));
XElement newTest = new XElement("TestForPackage",
                      from Tests in query.AsEnumerable()
                      select new  XElement("Tests",
                             new XElement("Dep_Code", Tests.Dep_Code),
                             new XElement("Dep_Name", Tests.Dep_Name),
                             new XElement("Test_Code", Tests.Test_Code),
                             new XElement("Test_Name", Tests.Test_Name),
                             new XElement("Sub_Test_Code", Tests.Sub_Test_Code),
                             new XElement("Sub_Test_Code", Tests.Sub_Test_Name)
                      ));

data.Element("TestsForPackage").Add(newTest);
data.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile.xml"));
```

It generates xml in the format below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TestsForPackage>
  <Test>
    <Dep_Code>BIOCH</Dep_Code>
    <Dep_Name>BIOCHEMISTRY</Dep_Name>
    <Test_Code>BGPP</Test_Code>
    <Test_Name>BLOOD GLUCOSE P.P.</Test_Name>
    <Sub_Test_Code />
    <Sub_Test_Name />
  </Test>

  <Test>
     <Dep_Code>BIOCH</Dep_Code>
     <Dep_Name>BIOCHEMISTRY</Dep_Name>
     <Test_Code>BGPP</Test_Code>
     <Test_Name>BLOOD GLUCOSE P.P.</Test_Name>
     <Sub_Test_Code />
     <Sub_Test_Name />
  </Test>

  <Test>
     <Dep_Code>BIOCH</Dep_Code>
     <Dep_Name>BIOCHEMISTRY</Dep_Name>
     <Test_Code>BGPP</Test_Code>
     <Test_Name>BLOOD GLUCOSE P.P.</Test_Name>
     <Sub_Test_Code />
     <Sub_Test_Name />
  </Test>      
</TestsForPackage>
```

However, I need to generate xml file in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TestsForPackage>
  <Test>
    <Dep_Code>BIOCH</Dep_Code>
    <Dep_Name>BIOCHEMISTRY</Dep_Name>
    <Test_Code>BGPP</Test_Code>
    <Test_Name>BLOOD GLUCOSE P.P.</Test_Name>
    <Sub_Test_Code />
    <Sub_Test_Name />
  </Test>

  <Test>
     <Dep_Code>BIOCH</Dep_Code>
     <Dep_Name>BIOCHEMISTRY</Dep_Name>
     <Test_Code>BGPP</Test_Code>
     <Test_Name>BLOOD GLUCOSE P.P.</Test_Name>
     <Sub_Test_Code />
     <Sub_Test_Name />
  </Test>

  <Test>
    <Dep_Code>BIOCH</Dep_Code>
     <Dep_Name>BIOCHEMISTRY</Dep_Name>
     <Test_Code>BGPP</Test_Code>
     <Test_Name>BLOOD GLUCOSE P.P.</Test_Name>
     <Sub_Test_Code />
     <Sub_Test_Name />
  </Test>

</TestsForPackage>
```

I know I am making some minor mistake but I don't know what it is.

Comment: It's not at all obvious what the difference between the expected and actual output is - partly because you've posted very large samples with huge amounts of whitespace. Also note that this question has nothing to do with ASP.NET as far as I can see.

Comment: I have generated Xml file by using linq to sql,thats why i give the tag as asp.net

Comment: LINQ to SQL and ASP.NET are completely different though! Just because you happen to be using ASP.NET somewhere doesn't mean the question is really *about* ASP.NET. It looks like it's probably just a LINQ to XML question, but I can't spot the difference between the expected format and what you're currently getting. Please clarify - and read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: The only difference I can see between the two XML files is an extra carriage return in the second. XML is about semantics, about meaning - the whitespace is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @coline=extra carriage is my problem

Comment: @jon =sorry jon i am new here,i keep your advice always

Comment: @user1023160: Well given that the formatting was all over the place, it's hard to tell exactly where that is... and my edits have removed at least *some* irrelevant whitespace. Where *exactly* is the difference? Be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is all about semantics, it is a mechanism for transmission and exchange of data. An XML parser doesn't care about the whitespace in your file. For this reason, XML writers do not allow you to control the whitespace output (other than giving your the option to pretty-print).

If you want to be specific about where the line-breaks are in your XML output, you are going to have to manipulate the XML output yourself using string manipulation.